# setting up rsync cron job, not executing

Tags: server, cron, rsync

So I have just setup my new Ubuntu Server 18.04. I have the main primary OS installed on an SSD, the second HDD (primary media drive) mounted to /media and the backup drive mounted to /mnt. I have set both /media and /mnt to be able to be written too without needing sudo permissions.

I wanted to setup a daily rsync backup from /media to /mnt.

So I ran

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Then at the bottom of the file I put

```
0 22 * * * rsync -av --delete /media /mnt
```

I did this about 1PM yesterday and I think this should have ran at about 10PM. I got up this morning and the cron job did not execute. Any ideas?

This is what the journal shows

```
Jan 19 21:17:01 grierserver CRON[23622]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root 
Jan 19 22:17:01 grierserver CRON[26812]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0) 
Jan 19 22:17:01 grierserver CRON[26813]: (root) CMD ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly) 
Jan 19 22:17:01 grierserver CRON[26812]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

Comment: Does `journalctl -u cron.service` shows that the `rsync` command did execute? You also can add `&> /tmp/rsync.log` to your crontab command to log the output ( `0 22 * * * rsync -av --delete /media /mnt &> /tmp/rsync.log` ).

Comment: This is what the journal shows "Jan 19 21:17:01 grierserver CRON[23622]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jan 19 22:17:01 grierserver CRON[26812]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jan 19 22:17:01 grierserver CRON[26813]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jan 19 22:17:01 grierserver CRON[26812]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
" I will add that line to the end.

Comment: You may want to add this to the question by editing the question.?

Comment: Consider using redirection so you can log all the -v output (and error messages)

Comment: In `cron` the environment is very simple (PATH and other environment variables are not what you have in a text screen or terminal window). Try with full path, `/usr/bin/rsync`, it may be enough for it to start working.

Answer (score 0):

By doing `sudo crontab -e`, you edited `root`'s `crontab` (I guess to ensure your backup executed as `root`).

However, `root`'s `crontab` has a field that `$USER` `crontab`s do not.

`root` `crontab` specifies the USERID to use in the 6th field, and the rest of the parameters move over.

See `man 5 crontab`, the `EXAMPLE SYSTEM CRON FILE` section.

You should specify (in `root`'s `crontab only)

```
0 22 * * * root rsync -av --delete /media /mnt
           ^^^^
```

But, a better way to do it is to wrap the `rsync` command in a `bash` script (which uses full `bash` syntax, is easy to change, test, add debug stuff, ...) and call that script from `cron`.

Comment: What you say is wrong. `sudo crontab -e` (=root's crontab) does *not* have a user field, only `/etc/crontab` (=system crontab) has.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so looks like it is working. Doesn't appear to run at 10 but does work. I noticed that by adding this code to the crontab without sudo it works just fine.

Another question I have is when I look in the folder which rsync is syncing too and I run an "ls" command, why do the new file being synced show in purple? Does the color just help me find them or does it mean something?